# Authenticate with TouchID automatically without showing any prompt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, touch-id, localauthentication

Implemented Biometric feature of accessing Touch ID for authentication purpose. But it always shows the system prompt.

[image]

How can I get rid of this? In some apps I observe whenever an user press the home button, the app gets logged in with out showing any prompt. How can I achieve such thing.

TIA

Comment: You question is a little confusing.  You show a Touch ID dialog but ask about Face ID. Face ID can complete very quickly if the user is looking at the device. Touch ID has to prompt the user to present their finger.

Comment: You don't have to use Touch ID; you can just store credentials or a token in the keychain. Any time you want to use biometric access then a dialog is shown. This is a privacy feature of iOS.